# Adding href link in string / super - string [Marzipano Java Script]

Tags: javascript, string

I searched the answer in marzipano js library albo in mdn, but cant' find simple answer how can i create a href link after br.

```
  "infoHotspots": [
    {
      "yaw": -0.439087126380523,
      "pitch": 0.018426225400929326,
      "title": "Eget leo",
      "text": "Fusce semper ante at lorem molestie, eu lacinia sem sollicitudin. Proin auctor lectus eu eros condimentum lacinia. Etiam laoreet in mauris eu auctor. <br> https://www.facebook.com/newlink"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Use an [anchor element `<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a): `"...<br> <a href='https://www.facebook.com/newlink'> link text goes here </a>"`

Comment: Thank you! Do you think i can put style="" inside each html element? or maybe give em class ?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can add a style attribute: `<a style=' ... '` or a class: `<a class=' ... '`

Comment: Thank you sir! Simpler than i thought :)